# TestNG - run tests in order impossible scenario?

Tags: testing, testng

I've tried many ways with no success and I'm starting to believe this is not achievable in TestNG and I just like to confirm with you.

I have web service I'm testing and I need to run few basic scenarios.

My current test methods, each with @Test annotation (each need to be testable as a single test):

- **dbResetTest**
- **clearCacheTest**
- **openURLTest**
- **loginTest**
- **actionXTest**
- **actionYTest**

I also need to run these scenarios consisting from above tests run IN ORDER:

1. Test login feature (**openURLTest** -> **dbResetTest** -> **clearCacheTest** -> **loginTest**)
2. Test X after login (**openURLTest** -> **dbResetTest** -> **clearCacheTest** -> **loginTest** -> **actionXTest**)
3. Test Y after clearing cache (**clearCacheTest** -> **actionYTest**)

The issue is, if I made tests from point 1 & 2 dependant on others I won't be able to run scenario 3 because **clearCacheTest** does not depend on any other in this particular scenario. I've tried running those test in order through xml and by using dependencies but with no success.

Of course I could make **actionYTest** to call **clearCacheTest** directly but then if **clearCacheTest** fails the report will show that **actionYTest** was the failing one which is what I try to avoid.

I'm pretty sure now what I need is not achievable in TestNG but maybe I'm wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your tactics slightly. Instead of perceiving these ~(dbResetTest, etc.) as test Classes you should make them test methods instead and use dependsOnMethods programatically (not from XML) instead of dependsOnGroups. Then you will be able to implement your required logic rather easily (every test is unique --> @Test annotation, every test is executed in certain priority --> use priority parameter). Then the 1,2,3 tests should be your test classes. So here it is how you do it:

```
public class LoginFeature {

   @Test (priority=1)
   public openURLTest(){
   } 

   @Test (priority=2, dependsOnMethods="openURLTest")
   public dbResetTest (){
   } 


   @Test (priority=3, dependsOnMethods="dbResetTest")
   public clearCacheTest (){
   }  

   @Test (priority=4, dependsOnMethods="clearCacheTest" )
   public loginTest(){
   } 



}
```

This way if something fails in between your tests the rest of scenarios will automatically be skipped and you won't need to call directly clearCacheTest.

Hope this helps!

---

***Update***

After OP's comment

Well again I think you kinda have of a design issue. For your methods to be called multiple times they need to sit somewhere that they are accessible. You are almost there with your approach but not quite. So here is how you can call  the methods; multiple times and run them every time from scratch (I'll show you the code first and then explain in detail):

*parent class*

```
 public class TestBase{
    //include here all your important methods *without* @Test Annotation

    public void dbReset(){
    //perform db reset
    }

    public void clearCache(){
    //clear browser cache
    }

    public boolean openURL(){
    //try to open test URL
    return didIreachTestURLSuccessfully;

    }

}
```

*child class*

```
public class loginFeature extends TestBase{


@Test (priority=1)
public void attemptToResetDataBase(){

dbReset();
}


@Test (priority=2, dependsOnMeth0ds="attemptToResetDataBase")
public void clearCacheTest(){

clearCache();
}


@Test (priority=3, dependsOnMeth0ds="clearCacheTest")
public void verifySuccessfulLogin(){

login();
}



}
```

So, you include all of your test methods in a parent class, called TestBase. Then you create your test (loginTest for example) with a class that extends TestBase. Now you can call your methods multiple times, treat them each time as an individual test and connect them with dependencies according to your needs (i.e I have each one of them depending on the prior method; but you could rearrange them and put them all to depend on one, or to no-one).

Because your test class inherits from TestBase you don't even need to create an object to access the internal methods; you can call them directly instead.

Hope this solves it for you, do not hesitate to write a comment if you need more info.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not quite what I was going to achieve. These tests I mentioned are already build as @Test methods. I want those methods to be called multiple times from other tests and other classes. For now when some test depends on clearCacheTest, it is called once and if another test also depends on clearCacheTest it will not be called anymore as it already passed... but I don't only want it to pass but actually do the job of clearing cache twice before those two tests.

Comment: Ok Jon got ya, will update my answer to reflect your update. I still think it is achievable though :)

Comment: Almost there ;) I've tried that approach at the very beginning and it even worked but soon I realised that it was giving me false test reports. You see, dbReset in this way is not defined as a test so when I run my test number 1 i.e. loginFeatureTest: (openURLTest -> dbResetTest -> clearCacheTest -> loginTest) and dbReset fail for some reason I will get report as if the whole loginFeatureTest failed and I'd like to see that it was actually dbResetTest fault. Maybe the only option is to call dbReset from inside a loginFeatureTest and assert it's result with a message?

Comment: Yes, you need a TestNG assertion to instill some intelligence in your tests. If you have your dependsOnMethods correct you should see all tests failing but see them failing depending on the assertion you do at the end of each test. So, all of the above methods need their own assertion.